# How convert PIL images from a continius Queue.queue to an numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a function that, when called, starts a continiuous Queue.queue of images.I need to convert each separate image into a separate numpy array.

```
 try:
        img = self.image_queue.get_nowait()
        self._image = numpy.array(img)
```

I understand correctly that a numpy.array cannot only work with individual images? How to do it right?

Comment: I am having a hard time working out what your question is - your code seems alright. Who/what is sending the images and how? What is the problem?

Comment: Images are frames from the camera.A special class takes them from this camera and upload them image_queue. I did not cite the code this class, as it seems to work correctly. In any case, single frames through the get() method are quite succesfully retrieved. This means that an continuous queue of images is being successfully formed. But I do not know how to properly convert separate images to separate np.array.